# Meteor Builds Returns Tar Instead Of Apk

Tags: android, meteor

When I run:

```
meteor build ~/Desktop/Builds --server <myPrivateServer>
```

I get a tar.gz in the folder instead of a apk.
It also returns this error:

```
/home/nateman/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: EACCES, unlink '/home/nateman/Desktop/KidzIdeaz/KidzIdeaz/.meteor/local/cordova-build/resources/android_hdpi.icon.png'
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/nateman/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at Object.rm_recursive (/tools/fs/files.js:270:9)
    at CordovaBuilder.writeConfigXmlAndCopyResources (/tools/cordova/builder.js:260:13)
    at CordovaProject.prepareFromAppBundle (/tools/cordova/project.js:158:13)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:966:24
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:356:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:349:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:347:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:321:26)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:958:20
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:268:13
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:261:29
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:259:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:250:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:249:19)
    at Object.main.captureAndExit (/tools/cli/main.js:270:29)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:957:10
    at buildCommand (/tools/cli/commands.js:1012:8)
    at Command.main.registerCommand._.extend.name [as func] (/tools/cli/commands.js:791:12)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1378:23
```

I have set the variables:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/home/nateman/Desktop/Android/tools:/home/nateman/Desktop/Adnroid/platform-tools"
ANDROID_HOME="/home/nateman/Desktop/Android
```

"

So how can I get an apk instead of the resulting tar.gz, or do I convert the tar.gz too an apk?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Do a `sudo chown -hR <yourUsername> <directory>`